# Selecting from a different array from an object based on an what page has been clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an object which has 4 arrays which basically tells me how many friends have stayed at a different room.  Instead of writing the same code for 4 different rooms I want to be able to select the appropriate array based on what room the user has clicked.  I imagine using this but I'm not sure the best way of doing it.

So instead of creating 4 different functions for the rooms I want to choose 'this' room and then run the function.

Does this make sense?

```
Student.friends = function(){
  var data = {
    'delux': ["Bob Smith","Jane Doe", "Bubba Hyde","Betsy Toheavens"],
    'shared': ['Bob Smith'],
    'animal': ["Bob Smith", "Jane Doe","Bubba Hyde"],
    'another': ["Bob Smith","Jane Doe"],
    'and-another': []
  }
  Student.delux(data)
}

Student.delux = function(data){
  var delux = data['delux'].sort() 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with jQuery. Add an event listener to each of your rooms which then does something with the array based on the Id of your room.

**Example**

HTML:

```
<div id="delux" class="room"></div>
<div id="shared" class="room"></div>
<div id="animal" class="room"></div>
<div id="another" class="room"></div>
<p id="friends"></p>
```

Javascript:

```
  var data = {
    'delux': ["Bob Smith","Jane Doe", "Bubba Hyde","Betsy Toheavens"],
    'shared': ['Bob Smith'],
    'animal': ["Bob Smith", "Jane Doe","Bubba Hyde"],
    'another': ["Bob Smith","Jane Doe"],
    'and-another': []
  }

// selects all DOM objects with the css class ".room" and
// adds an event listener to those objects which fires when clicked
$("body").on("click", ".room", function(){
    // you can then access your array with data[this.id],
    // here I just display its content on the page 
    $("#friends").html(data[this.id].toString());
});
```

Working Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/p6vur8oj/2/